# Extract string after first occurrence of a string pattern

Tags: r, string

I'm having trouble extracting all the text that occurs after the first occurrence of the word 'PRODUCTS'. The text I'm working with is below and is stored in

`test$description`

(There is more text but R truncates the last part)

```
[1] "Hey guys! Been wanting to film a Get Ready With Me for a while, just to sit back and chill and chit chat with you all! It has been a MINUTE since I have done one of these so I hope you enjoy this first impressions get ready with me :D Love you guys! \n\nDONT FORGET TO HIT SUBSCRIBE! :D \n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nFACE PRODUCTS : \n\nH2O Green Tea Matcha Facial Essence -  \nMILK Makeup Blur Stick - \nLoreal Total Coverage Foundation - \nGallany Concealer - \n\nBecca Soft Light Powder - \nPixie X Maryam NYC Glow and Bronze Palete - \nClinique Honey Cheek Pop Blush -\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nEYE PRODUCTS! \n\nColourpop Pressed Eyeshadows -  <truncated>
```

When I use:
`sub(".*PRODUCTS",'',test$description)`

I get:

```
[1] "! \n\nColourpop Pressed Eyeshadows - \n\nTarte Cosmetics Fake Away Pencil - \n\nKat Vond D Trooper Eyeliner - \n\nNubounsom Dragon Li Lashes - Use code MANNYMUA to save 20% - \n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nLIPS \n\nMorphe Brushes Liquid Lipstick in the shade Mood - USE CODE MANNYMUA to save money -\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nBRUSHES AND TOOLS - \n\nMorphe Brushes - use code \"MANNYMUA\" all caps for 10% off everything! - \n- \nMorphe E2 Bronzer Brush - \nMorphe E4 Blush Brush - \nMorphe MB13 Nose Contour - \nMorphe M510 Highlight Brush - \n\nEYES:\nE2... <truncated>
```

So only everything after the second occurrence of 'PRODUCTS'

When I use: `sub(".*PRODUCTS ",'',test$description)`

I get:

```
[1] ": \n\nH2O Green Tea Matcha Facial Essence -  \nMILK Makeup Blur Stick - \n\nLoreal Total Coverage Foundation - \nGallany Concealer - \n\nBecca Soft Light Powder - \n\nPixie X Maryam NYC Glow and Bronze Palete - \n\nClinique Honey Cheek Pop Blush - \n\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nEYE PRODUCTS! \n\nColourpop Pressed Eyeshadows - \n\nTarte Cosmetics Fake Away Pencil - \n\nKat Vond D Trooper Eyeliner - \n\nNubounsom Dragon Li Lashes - Use code MANNYMUA to save 20% - \n\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nLIPS \n\nMorphe Brushes Liquid Lipstick in the shade Mood - USE CODE MANNYMUA to save money... <truncated>
```

I think the issue is the space between 'PRODUCTS' and the colon in the first occurrence and the lack of space between 'PRODUCTS' and the exclamation point in the second occurrence. But I'm trying to tell R just to look for the string 'PRODUCTS'. How can I get it to ignore the spacing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost had it.  Instead use `sub(".*?PRODUCTS",'',test$description)`
Note added `?`, no space after PRODUCTS.   By default, the matching is "greedy";  it matches as much as it can, so `.*PRODUCTS` goes until the *last* copy of PRODUCTS.  Adding the `?` turns off greedy matching so it only goes to the first instance.